# Unit-Of-Order in WLI JMSControl

Tags: jms, weblogic, weblogic-integration

One of our clientes is intented to use the [Unit-Of-Order Weblogic Server Feature (UOO)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/jms/uoo.html).

Everything is OK using UOO in pure java code for sending JMS Messages with custom UOO Names, as well as propagating the UOO Name in Aqualogic Service Bus from the Proxy Service to a Business Service (both using JMS as the transfer protocol).

However, using UOO in Weblogic Integration along with WLI JMSControl, does no work properly.

Consider this code:

```
@com.bea.control.JMSControl.Properties(value = {
        @com.bea.control.JMSControl.PropertyValue(name = "JMS_BEA_UnitOfOrder", value = "MyUOONameFromWLI"),
        @com.bea.control.JMSControl.PropertyValue(name = "MyCustomProperty", value = "MyCustomValue") })
public void sendTextMessage(String payload);
```

It sends the property `MyCustomProperty` to the JMS consumer, but the property `JMS_BEA_UnitOfOrder` - related to UOO Name - is ignored. The default User-generated UOO name is used instead.

**So, how to customize my UOO Name using Weblogic JMSControl?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that it has no support!